# Can I use fuzzy matchers with multiple possible types in Karate?

Tags: karate

The API I'm testing may return a string or a number for many fields. I've been able to use a self validation expression to check this behavior: `{ a: '#? typeof _ === "number" || typeof _ === "string"' }`.

Is there (or should there be) a way to do this with Karate's fuzzy match markers? Like `{ a: '#string OR #number'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think this is IMO a badly designed API and I don't want to bloat the syntax to solve for these.

Note that you can make this more elegant as follows, so you can write this function once, define it "globally" and re-use to your heart's content:

```
* def isNumOrStr = function(x){ return typeof x === 'number' || typeof x === 'string' }
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* match foo == { a: '#? isNumOrStr(_)' }
* def bar = { a: 'z' }
* match bar == { a: '#? isNumOrStr(_)' }
```